# Parse date time with PM/AM

Tags: c#

I want to parse the following date-time format:

```
8/1/2013 3:52:05 PM
```

What should I use for format ?

```
DateTime.ParseExact("8/1/2013 3:52:05 PM", "format", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) provides clear examples of how to use ParseExact, including the `format` parameter.

Comment: Obligatory link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx. specifically `"tt"` for the AM/PM indicator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

> `"tt"` - The AM/PM designator.

So your format string should be: `M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt`

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("8/1/2013 3:52:05 PM", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

prints `2013-08-01 15:52:05`

**But, you can easily do the same without specifying the format:**

```
DateTime.Parse("8/1/2013 3:52:05 PM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"))
```

Works just fine. Your input is formatted using `en-US` format.

Comment: Careful of your AM/PM note, depends on your .NET version. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx): In the .NET Framework 4, the ParseExact method throws a FormatException if the string to be parsed contains an hour component and an AM/PM designator that are not in agreement. In the .NET Framework 3.5 and earlier versions, the AM/PM designator is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("8/1/2013 3:52:05 PM", "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Output will be;

```
1/8/2013 3:52:05 PM
```

Here a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/1oCEwt).

Further reading;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)